# Webbrowser in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I trying open page with Russian symbols.

```
webbrowser.open('https://www.google.com/?q=привет')
```

But I have this in browser: https://www.google.com/?q=??????

Comment: it's ok. mozilla tab opened with (?q=привет) on my machine. 

just check if your computer or browser supports cyrillic symbols

Answer (score 1):

Use a unicode string.

```
webbrowser.open(u'https://www.google.com/?q=привет')
```

You'll probably also want to use UTF-8 encoding for your source file, so make sure your editor actually saves in UTF-8 and add this to the top of the program

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

Comment: I tried but I have this error:  **UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 47-50: ordinal not in range(128)**

Comment: Probably because you are doing something you didn't write in your example. Read [Unicode HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html#the-unicode-type) Suffice it to say that whatever you are trying to do, can be done in Unicode. You may have to encode your strings such as `u''.join(url, query).encode('utf-8')`